# How to download read-only recordings on Teams

Tags: onedrive, recording

Is there any way to download a read-only recording from a Teams class (without recording the screen)?
I have a shared OneDrive of lecture recordings, some can be downloaded and some cannot.

Thanks for your help and stay safe.

Answer (score 28):

You can download videos using **ffmpeg**.

> Before following these instructions, Please install **ffmpeg** to your PC.

1. Go to the recording URL. Now you can view the video but you have no option to download the video.
2. open dev tools in the browser and go to the Network tab.
3. Then reload the webpage again.
4. In the network tab, search the following command using the search area.

   ```
   videomanifest?provider
   ```

[image: search result]

5. click on the highlighted area and you can see the right panel is viewing some contents.

[image: content of search]

6. Scroll up to the top of this panel.
7. Now you can find the URL under **Request URL**.
8. Copy that entire URL.
9. Use this below command in cmd.

   ```
   ffmpeg -i "PASTE_YOUR_COPIED_REQUEST_URL_HERE" -codec copy NAME_OF_DOWNLOADFILE.mp4
   ```
10. You can see downloading the video.

Comment: Hi @shalitha, where does ffmpeg saves the video by default? How to change directory.

Comment: @Sthln replace the 'NAME_OF_DOWNLOADFILE' with your path

Answer (score 2):

For this entry listed as highest upvoted:
"*You can download videos using ffmpeg.
Before following these instructions, Please install ffmpeg to your PC.
Go to the recording URL. Now you can view the video but you have no option to download the video.
open dev tools in the browser and go to the Network tab.
Then reload the webpage again.
In the network tab, search the following command using the search area.*"

Minor edit:
Still, find the "videomanifest?provider"
But right-click copy, copy the link address, and replace the PASTE_YOUR_COPIED_REQUEST_URL_HERE listed above (Make sure you keep the ""):

```
ffmpeg -i "PASTE_YOUR_COPIED_REQUEST_URL_HERE" -codec copy NAME_OF_DOWNLOADFILE.mp4
```

[Picture of Menu/Copy Link Address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75uOe.png)

Answer (score 0):

From my own testings I found out that:

1. you can always download your **own recordings** (=they're located in your OneDrive)
2. you can download if you are the **meeting organizer** (=recording is located in someone else's OneDrive but you can download nonetheless)

---

Test setup: 2 different Team meetings (scheduled from Outlook) within same organization, 1 with me as organizer, 1 with the other person - and then we both started a recording each. The organizer could always download.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I will have to get in contact with the meeting organizer in that case. Stay safe!